# Make iTunes stop prompting me for my username and password

Tags: macos, itunes, password, preferences, dialog

On OSX Lion, iTunes keeps prompting me to enter my username and password to "sign in to enable this computer for automatic downloads." In the past I tried checking the box to remember my password but it kept forgetting, so now I just disabled the "always check for available downloads" option in Prefs -> Store. It still prompts me. It drives me crazy.

Is there a way to get it to stop prompting for my password, so it will just behave like a well-behaved offline music library manager, and only ask me for my username and password when I open the iTunes store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need to do is Sign OUT of the itunes store!

If you are signed in, each time you fire up iTunes, it will try to login again and ask for your password. Sign out and it won't bother you!

Comment: But then the automatic download will stop working as well, doesn't it?

Comment: I haven't tried this b/c my preferences have changed; I now want to stay signed in w/o having it prompt for p/w. But I'll accept this answer since it seems logical and meets the terms of the original question. If anyone tries this and it doesn't work, please let me know....

Comment: how can you sign out if you arent signed in ?

Answer (score 4):

Try to resetting your warnings, as suggested in this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3462257?start=0&tstart=0):

> Open iTunes/preferences/advanced, then hit the box in the middle that says "reset warnings".

Comment: I tried this + resetting the iTunes Store cache, and so far I have not been prompted for my pw. I will continue to monitor the behavior for a week and if after restarts, device connections, etc. it still doesn't repeat, accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: After syncing my iPad, it has again started prompting at startup at least once per OSX login session (not sure if more per session). Any thoughts?

Comment: If it is just promting once, perhaps removing the device association in your Apple count may work.

Comment: I get the same behavior. It prompts me for pw at least once per OSX session, and at most once per iTunes session; I'm not sure if many times across iTunes sessions in a single OSX session.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you might have duplicate iTunes password entries in your keychain.

1. Open your Keychain.app and search for entries with "iTunes" in it
2. delete those iTunes entries (you need to know your passwords!)
3. reboot (to clear out your cache)

Now try again.

Comment: Nope, just one...

Comment: Since the problem somehow seems ro be related to your iPad sync, I would try and do a complete backup/restore cycle of that iPad.

Comment: Ahh, good thought, but the problem has persisted over a year of neither having nor syncing an iPad.

Comment: Well, then I am slowly running out if options :-) Do you know [PowerTunes](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/powertunes/)? It's an iTunes Library manager and maintenance tool. You might want to give it a shot. They charge 19.95 U$, however, there is a trial version. Maybe it can do some magic by rebuilding your iTunes Library...

Comment: I also have this problem.  iTunes doesn't have an entry in keychains.  Yosemite

Answer (score 1):

Possibly sign out of iTunes store, then click "Deauthorize This Computer" under store tab in menu bar, then reauthorize your computer, then sign back in to iTunes store.

Comment: I know this is for MacOS, but I was having the same problem under Windows 7, and this is the only suggestion that actually worked for me.

Comment: I spoke too soon. After a couple of days the problem came back.

Comment: I don't want to sign in.  I want to remain signed out.

Answer (score 0):

I have an older laptop running OS X.  I finally found out how to stop iTunes from asking for a password with each restore.  Click **System Preferences** > **Users and Groups** > **Login items** > deselect iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Apple ID password on my iPhone and then *my Mac* kept asking me to enter and re-enter my password prompting again and again.

**I killed iTunes in the Activity Monitor** (Force-quit the app) and restarted it. Helped like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I am running Windows 7. I was getting the popup every 2 min until I got mad and **just clicked the "X" to close the window that asks for password instead of complying with the machine**. It hasn't prompted me for a login since and I have been commissioning multiple iPads for use at our Production Plant.

Comment: I click the [x] and the box reappears.  Sometimes there are 5 boxes on top of each other.  I need to click 5 times.

Answer (score -2):

I just deleted iTunes no more sign ins. Hooray.